# React-Native authentication with a server using Azure AD

Tags: azure, react-native, authentication, server, azure-active-directory

I am trying to authenticate to a server from my React-Native app using Azure AD.

Now, I don't understand what is a redirect URI and I don't understand where should I put my server's URL in Azure and what URL should I call from my React-Native app.

Documentation for it is quite confusing.

Comment: @TonyJu thank you for your answer. As soon as I will look at it, I will come back to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't understand what is a redirect URI

For React-Native app, the redirect_url is optional. Refer to this [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-azure-ad) for more details.

**An url that ADLoginView will be redirect when login success, this property is optional.**

> I don't understand where should I put my server's URL in Azure and
>   what URL should I call from my React-Native app.

You needn't put your server's url in Azure.But you need to add authentication to your server. Then you can call your server api as normal, but with the Authorization header. This [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore) will help you to understand better though it is using aspnetcore.

You need to create register two applications in Azure portal. **Client app** and **server app**. You will get the access token via your native app and then use it to access your server app.

Comment: To be honest I dont understand your explanation. First of all, you are saying that I need to have 2 App Registration in Azure right? In my React-Native app, the ClientID of which one should I use?

Comment: FYI I can already login to my server, I just send a request to my server with my credentials. I want to authenticate via Azure to track user sessions.

Comment: @bimixbimix Yes, you need two App Registration. You React-Native app should be client app id. Have you authenticated your server with Azure AD? Which development language did your server use?

Comment: The problem is that I havent develop that server and i dont have access to it, so you mean that I have to do some configuration in the server as well?

Comment: @bimixbimix Yes, you are right. If you want to  protect your server by using azure ad. You need to configure it.

Comment: @bimixbimix That's why we need register two applications in Azure portal